# php file to pdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

I was converting a HTML file to PDF using dompdf. I managed to get the desired result but a problem arose, the HTML file needs to be converted to PHP because it will receive data from a form (from another file)!

The dompdf in this case doesn't work and it not shows the result of what was written in the form.

Comment: What about creating a temporary html file from the contents of the form then changing that to pdf and deleting it afterwards?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968454/php5-pdf-generation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your html file automaticaly in temp. After request to your php file, your file generates automaticaly a .html file (in temp), then create your pdf from this file.

Comment: It seems to me to be an effective solution ... but how do I do that? I was looking for examples with javascript / jQuery but ended up having the same problem above. Where do I run this command after the information in the form has been processed?

Comment: You do not necessarily need to create a temporary file. You could build your HTML from the form submission, capture this in a variable (using output buffering, for example), and then pass the variable to `$dompdf->load_html()`. In this way you would create your PHP as if you were going to just return an HTML document, but as a last step create the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you search is a template Engine to replace values in a HTML file.

There are some Engines like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/), [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

You can parse your HTML file and with the HTML return you can create your PDF file.

Perhaps its a bit oversized for your case but you could build your own short engine and parse your HTML file and replace your specified Tags with the form values.